# Delete excel workbook connection on external document or launch VBA on external file

Tags: vba, excel, external, group-policy

I am facing a problem with excel files given to managers. They have copied files to their computers and in these files are already written workbook connection string. But files in our server were updated, we put versions on them, however people are lazy to download them from server. Is there a way to launch through group-policy (or any another way) an VBA script that could delete workbook connection strings if version of file does not match the one that is placed in server??
VBA is easy, but do not know how to launch automatically on external files.

```
    sub deleteConnections()
For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
cn.Delete
Next cn
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not impossible, you could put that code within

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

In `ThisWorkbook` section of each file. It would delete the connection on opening. If you'd add some code to compare the files with the ones on server, then that would do exactly what you're looking for, though not exactly the way you've asked

Comment: Dani, thank you, but how could i enter that vba, if file exists on another computer and maanger is not sending it to me? I need to do this somehow automatically

Comment: That's a really good point, which I didn't consider. If you can, you could try removing/renaming the data source so they're forced to use new files, otherwise this might be a good question for you system admin, they should be able to provide you the answer.

Comment: If I rename data source in computer, excel still works as we included login id and password into excell workbook connection string:/ so the only thing that we thought, is to change Oracle schema name(connection string is linked to Oracle), which we can't. That's why we are looking for a way to do it on group policy somehow...

Comment: All I can think of now is running a script which would find a file and run the macro if found. Sorry I couldn't help, hope you will find your answer soon.